# MySQL native error handling vs anticipated error handling for Unique Values

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `email` and what I would usually do, when registering a new user, is to run a `SELECT` on the table for the provided email prior to `INSERT` a new user.

I just read a tutorial where the dev relies on the `UNIQUE` index of the column to throw an error if the email record already exists. He used MongoDB, I use MySQL.

On one hand it makes sense to spare a query per insert but on the other having DB errors doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on the other having DB errors doesn't feel right.

WHY? Instead your application take the overhead of checking for existence first and then insert the record; better have a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on your `email` column and if insert fails due to duplicacy then catch that error in your application and display a validation message to user saying `email` already exists.

Comment: Yea, if the emails are supposed to be unique, it's best to have UNIQUE constraint on them and use that for validation. It's the most robust way. There's no way to accidentally let a non-unique email slip into the database.